# Swipe to previous / next post URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe, swipe-gesture

Is it possible to navigate to previous / next post using swipe gesture on mobile / tablet device?

For example to follow prev / next link with certain id or class.

I can put any ID or class to dynamically generated links for previous and next post URLs like this:

```
<a id="prev-link" class="left-previous" href="">some link</a>
<a id="next-link" class="right-next" href="">other link</a>
```

I guss it can be done with jQuery, plus something more. Is this some way to tell it to opet link with some id/class on swipe gesture left and right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly, you can use jQuery Mobile library (https://jquerymobile.com/) to handle swipe events:

```
$("selector").on("swipe",function(event){...})
$("selector").on("swipeleft",function(event){...})
$("selector").on("swiperight",function(event){...})
```